# Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException Unable to create layer for WebView (Crashes on Lenove K5 Note Android 6.0)

Tags: android, webview

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException
Unable to create layer for WebView @2aad100
android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce (MessageQueue.java)
android.os.MessageQueue.next (MessageQueue.java:328)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5740)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:905)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:766)
```

I received a `android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce (MessageQueue.java)` crash from the firebase Crashlytics, but frequent crashes are only from a **Lenove K5 Note device with Android 6.0 OS** devices. Only affects Android 6.0 Lenove K5 note device.

I am using webview in my App but I have no idea how to reproduce or what the cause might be. Does anyone have any suggestions as to where I should start looking?

Comment: Have you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

adding android:hardwareAccelerated="false" to application tag in manifest might solve your issue.

Comment: This is not a good solution. It makes everything super Slow and messed up.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error was `Unable to create layer for RNCWebViewManager$f, size 1080x9661 exceeds max size 8192` and triggered a crash on **Android 8 Samsung and Huawei devices**.

**Limiting the webview height to about 2720 should prevent a crash**

For safety I used:

```
const { height, scale: dimScale } = Dimensions.get('window');
const ANDROID8_WEBVIEW_HEIGHT_LIMIT = Math.trunc(0.9 * height * dimScale);
```

and applied it only for Samsung and Huawei using react-native-device-info getBrand:

```
getBrand()?.match(/samsung|huawei/i);
```

Note: `2720` should work too, I preferred using the 0.9 and that calculation just to make sure I don't have surprised on different device types.

This was the only workaround I found to keep the `hardwareAccelerated` `true`